# Does Google Cloud Dataflow support stateful processing? ERROR: Workflow failed

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm using stateful processing in a streaming python Beam pipeline in order to detect when a field of a JSON message changes. When running using DirectRunner it works fine, but using DataflowRunner I get a "Workflow failed." error before the job can even start.

The function that uses stateful processing:

```py
class DetectChangeFn(DoFn):
    BAG_SPEC: BagStateSpec = BagStateSpec('changes', StrUtf8Coder())

    def __init__(self, field: str, *unused_args, **unused_kwargs):
        super().__init__(*unused_args, **unused_kwargs)
        self.field: str = field

    def process(self, element: Tuple[str, Dict], bag: BagRuntimeState = DoFn.StateParam(BAG_SPEC)) -> Iterable[Dict]:
        prev: List[str] = list(bag.read())
        current: str = str(element[1][self.field])

        if len(prev) == 0:
            bag.add(current)
        elif current != prev[0]:
            bag.clear()
            bag.add(current)
            yield element[1]
```

The error log message I get is very opaque and does not help all that much:

```json
{
 insertId: "ivmrqmc2os"  
 labels: {
  dataflow.googleapis.com/job_id: "2021-06-16_07_32_29-2286715838537053772"   
  dataflow.googleapis.com/job_name: "xxx"   
  dataflow.googleapis.com/log_type: "system"   
  dataflow.googleapis.com/region: "europe-west1"   
 }
 logName: "projects/xxx/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fjob-message"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2021-06-16T14:32:44.452175552Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   job_id: "2021-06-16_07_32_29-2286715838537053772"    
   job_name: "xxx"    
   project_id: "xxx"    
   region: "europe-west1"    
   step_id: ""    
  }
  type: "dataflow_step"   
 }
 severity: "ERROR"  
 textPayload: "Workflow failed."  
 timestamp: "2021-06-16T14:32:43.507731791Z"  
}
```

I'm using Apache Beam 2.30.0 with Python 3.8.
Is stateful processing supported in Google Cloud Dataflow or am I missing something?

**(EDIT)** Added template build and deploy commands:

```sh
python -m main \
    --runner DataflowRunner \
    --streaming \
    --save_main_session \
    --setup_file ./setup.py \
    --project $PROJECT \
    --staging_location $STAGING_LOCATION \
    --temp_location $TEMP_LOCATION \
    --template_location "$TEMPLATE"
```

```sh
gcloud dataflow jobs run "my-dataflow-job" \
    --enable-streaming-engine \
    --disable-public-ips \
    --gcs-location "$TEMPLATE" \
    --subnetwork $SUBNET \
    --num-workers $NUM_WORKERS \
    --max-workers $MAX_WORKERS \
    --region $REGION \
    --service-account-email $SERVICE_ACCOUNT
```

I'm not specifying any experiments explicitly, these are used by default in the Dataflow job: ['use_fastavro', 'runner_harness_container_image=gcr.io/cloud-dataflow/v1beta3/harness:2.30.0', 'use_multiple_sdk_containers']

**(EDIT 2)** Also, I'm getting the exact same error and behaviour when using the new WriteToBigQuery(with_auto_sharding=True) parameter.

Comment: Can you mention the command you used to start the pipeline including any experiments ?

Comment: Is your pipeline batch or streaming? Or, to put in terms of Beam: do you have any unbounded inputs? Dataflow will default to batch for a pipeline with all bounded inputs. Tests may trigger this issue, unfortunately, because they will often be bounded finite data.

Comment: @chamikara I've just edited the question to include the build and deploy commands I used

Comment: @KennKnowles It's a streaming pipeline, it reads data from various Pub/Sub subscriptions and writes it to BigQuery and another Pub/Sub topic. The stateful DoFn is right before the Pub/Sub write.

Comment: Thanks. It's surprising that you are getting a "Workflow failed" without any other details. Given that you received a job ID (2021-06-16_07_32_29-2286715838537053772) it's possible that there are other errors or more details regarding this error in Google Cloud logs. See here: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/troubleshooting-your-pipeline

Comment: @chamikara I've looked at the logs and there's not much there. The issue seems to be caused by the Dataflow fusion optimizations on the stateful DoFn, and I was able to fix it with a Reshuffle() step before the DoFn. Also, the same error pops up when using the new WriteToBigQuery(with_auto_sharding=True) parameter, and it's also fixed with a Reshuffle() step before writing to BigQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the issue by preventing the Dataflow service from performing fusion optimizations on the stateful DoFn.

To do so, I've added a Reshuffle() step right before the stateful DoFn.

This is one of the methods to prevent fusion optimizations described in the Dataflow docs: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#preventing-fusion

I've discovered this by looking at the logs right before the "Workflow failed." error occurred. There was a "Fusing consumer DoFnName into Stateful DoFn/KV DoFn" (edited for simplicity) that looked like it might be the cause of the error.